# Optimising program which finds the central binomial coefficients 2n choose n modulo (2n+1)

Tags: optimization, modulo, binomial-coefficients

I am trying to find positive integers n satisfying the two conditions:

1. 2n+1 is not a prime number.
2. 2n choose n is congruent to (-1)^n modulo (2n+1)

I have checked up to 950000 and have only found n=2953. It gets very slow after this though, since I am using GMP to calculate the binomial coefficient 2n choose n which are by now a few hundred thousand digits long. Since I am only interested in the remainder of the binomial coefficient modulo 2n+1, I feel like there should be a more efficient way of doing this, without actually having to calculate the binomial coefficient. I thought about taking the remainder modulo 2n+1 after each multiplication to prevent the numbers from getting large, but I am not exactly sure how to do this since I would need to work out the modular multiplicative inverse of n!, but 2n+1 is not a prime number so this inverse will not exist, and I'm not sure how to express 2n choose n (in general) as a product of integers. Any ideas would be appreciated. I am probably missing something quite simple.

My code is below:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <gmp.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  unsigned long long int n;
  int isprime=1;
  mpz_t a; // GMP long integer
  mpz_init(a); 
  for (n=1;n<=1000000;n++) {
    for (int i=2;i*i<=n;i++) { // testing if n is prime
    if ((2*n+1) % i == 0) {
      isprime=0;
      break;
    }
    }
    if (isprime == 0) { 
      mpz_bin_uiui(a,2*n,n); // Setting a equal to the binomial coefficient 2n choose n
      if (n % 2 == 0) { 
    mpz_sub_ui(a,a,1); // a-- if n is even
      }
      else {
    mpz_add_ui(a,a,1); // a++ if n is odd
      }
      mpz_cdiv_r_ui(a,a,2*n+1); // a = a % (2*n+1)
      if (mpz_cmp_ui(a,0)==0) {
    cout << n << endl;
      }
    }
    isprime=1;
  }
}
```

Comment: I think I will try this approach https://fishi.devtail.io/weblog/2015/06/25/computing-large-binomial-coefficients-modulo-prime-non-prime/

Comment: You have a mistake in your code-  you check primality by dividing by all divisors `<= sqrt(N)`, however you need to be checking all (primes) `<= sqrt(2 * N + 1)`. As unlikely as it may seem that a solution would have all prime factors larger than `sqrt(N)`, my python solver found an additional solution in the same range: `597324`, which I verified to be correct on [wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(2*597324+choose+597324)+mod+(2+*+597324+%2B+1)).

Comment: Have you had any success with the link you provided? I looked into that solution, but it seemed to be a bit too loop-heavy to benefit from speed gains due reducing the numbers mod M.

Comment: Woops. Thanks for pointing that out. I haven't tried it yet but it is polynomial time so it should be a lot faster than mine.

Comment: My approach was to compute enough of `2n choose n` to eliminate the divisor (while remaining strictly an integer), store the value, and compute the rest using modular arithmetic. Then for `2(n+1) choose (n+1)`, restore the intermediate result, do a few multiplications / divisions to transition to the "new" intermediate result, and again compute the rest via modular arithmetic.

Comment: The issue I ran into was that the test for if I can divide by the divisor evenly is slow for larger `N` due to the number of digits involved. I can represent the number in terms of its prime factorization to nearly completely eliminate this cost, but then converting it back to a single value to test primality becomes slow. In the end I used a hybrid approach, but there's probably a better solution yet.